# Triangles and ellipses in the plane!

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

This might be a trivial question; however, it got me quite confused. Let's say I have a 2D plane, and I am randomly put ellipses in this plane. Then if I don't care about the positions and rotations of these ellipses in the plane, I can classify all of them with two numbers (a, b) which, e.g. correspond to minor and major axes. I can organise these two numbers in a matrix

$$ M_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix}
1/a^2 & 0\\
0 & 1/b^2
\end{pmatrix}, $$
so that now any of these ellipses, positioned anywhere in the plane, however rotated are described by the expression:

$$ (r - r_0)_n(r - r_0)_m R_{ni}(\phi)R_{mj}(\phi)M_{ij}=1,$$

where $R_{nm}(\phi)$ is a rotation matrix in the plane

$$ R_{ij}(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi\\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix} $$

that rotates the ellipse around the origin by angle $\phi$, and $r_0=(x_0,y_0)$ is a vector that displaces the ellipse to some point at position $(x_0,y_0)$ away from the origin.
My point here is simply that I am able to classify all the ellipses in the plane by two parameters (a,b) and the rest are just rotations and displacements.

Now, my question is how to do the same type of descriptions for triangles? I naturally expect I should be able to use just three numbers (e.g. lengths of three sides) to classify all the triangles.
And the rest should be again just displacements and rotations the same as above.
But how can I do that? Can one write down some equations analogous to what I have above for ellipse that would describe this procedure of rotating and displacing the triangle?

Comment: You could do the following. Assume the side lengths are $a\le b\le c$; let $P$ be the point where $b$ and $c$ meet. Lay $P$ at the origin, with $c$ along the positive $x$-axis. From there, you can rotate about the origin and translate. This won't have as clean a formula as your ellipses, though.

Comment: I don't know about any particularly useful formulas, but you must be able to use reflexion as well. (It is possible to have two congruent triangles that cannot be overlaid on top of each other by using only rotations and translations.)

Comment: In fact, if you have two congruent triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$, then if $A\ne A'$ you can use one reflexion to map $A'$ into $A$ (and $B', C'$ into $B'', C''$). Now, if $B\ne B''$, you can use another reflexion with the axis passing through $A$ which will map $B''$ to $B$ (and $C$ into $C'''$). Now, in case $C'''\ne C$, this means that the final reflexion over $AB$ will map $C'''$ into $C$. You will end up creating an isometry made up as a composition of up to three reflexions.

Comment: @StinkingBishop ah, yes right, I will have to use some sort of party matrix in addition to the rotation.

Comment: So I was just thinking, would not two ellipses do the trick? Something like the minimal area one I can put my triangle in, and another, smaller of maximal area that fits in the triangle. Maybe a circle and ellipse would be optimal since these are three parameters as I need. The rotations translations and parity I can then do as above! How does this sound?

Comment: You can set a vertex at $(0,0)$, another at $(0,a)$ and the third one at $(b,c)$: three numbers $(a,b,c)$ will identify a triangle.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca That's the same as my suggestion, but without the restriction on the lengths.